# Hyper-V Ubuntu 12.04: Mouse scroll wheel doesnt work

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, mouse-scroll, hyper-v

I've been trying to setup an Ubuntu 12.04 workstation on a Hyper-V virtual machine (MS Windows Server 2008 R2) and I need some help with the mouse driver.

The mouse responds fine in general: the cursor's moving, left/right click works OK and also when I press the wheel windows are changing and tabs are closing.

Everything EXCEPT scrolling: Then nothing happens, except that the cursor's appearing on the upper left corner of my VM desktop and when I move the mouse it appears back where it was.

Can someone guide me how to solve this? It gets really annoying...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a bug with Windows Server 2008 r2 Hyper-V per RedHat:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=872519

Their research shows the problem is fixed in server 2012.

Comment: "Supported Guest Operating Systems 
This version of Linux Integration Services supports the following guest operating systems:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.7, 5.8, 6.0-6.3 x86 and x64
CentOS 5.7, 5.8, 6.0-6.3 x86 and x64"
Are you sure I can apply them to Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: http://baudlabs.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-integration-services-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Worked for them :)

Comment: `administrator@gnorasis-ununtu:~/linuxic/RHEL63$ ./install.sh

Installing the Linux Integration Services for Microsoft Hyper-V...

./install.sh: line 28: rpm: command not found

Kmod RPM installation failed, Exiting.`
Well it seems that the installing script failed.. :/

Comment: In the SxS (step by step) it mentions the services should be built in (since 10.10).  The SxS includes instructions on how to activate the IC's.  I edited my answer to match.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've also tested that earlier so everything seems to be running fine (http://i.imgur.com/e3sIxyj.png) but still no scrolling..

Comment: Are you using hyper-v on 08r2 or 2012?

Comment: Im on 2008 R2. I also try now to include **hv_mouse** service I read about here: http://baudlabs.com/overview-of-linux-integration-services-ics-for-hyper-v/ and see what I can get..

Comment: The RedHat team determined the problem to be with HyperV on 08r2.  Their research showed Microsoft fixed the problem in 2012  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=872519

Comment: God damn.. that sucks! The bug description is identical to mine. I guess there's no workaround for this right now.. Please edit your answer accordingly and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help no matter what!

Comment: If you want to test, microsoft is still offering release preview server 2012 r2 (free for testing purposes) incase you want to try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately the server is hosted on a network location so upgrading it, it's not an option. Thanks for all anyway!